# Three.js - How do I change the size of a scene?

Tags: three.js

I have created a basic scene with a cube that takes up the bottom quarter of my screen and I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that it completely expands to full screen when the scene is click, or if there's an easier option such as a button or scrolling down to expand (and back up to make smaller again) I'm open to that too, just trying to figure it out for now.

I tried adding an event listener for click but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Could you show your tests so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.